# Laravel Error:Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6.2

I am showing error from a Blade view. I haven't idea why this is happening. This code running well another computer.

Error mentions this line:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="this_line">
```

I am stuck with this.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="isUrgent" value="0">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="isUrgent" class="form-check-input"
                                                    {{ old('isUrgent')?'checked':'' }}    value="1">
                                                    Urgent
                                                    <i class="input-frame"></i></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12" id="this_line"> 
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="isCustomerReq" value="0">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="isCustomerReq" class="form-check-input"
                                                    {{ old('isCustomerReq')?'checked':'' }}     value="1">
                                                    Customer Request
                                                    <i class="input-frame"></i></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you certain that the code you posted above is actually what is generating this error?

Comment: I am not sure..this is code set acoording to  laravel  ErrorException line number. I edited that line id as "this line" thank you

Comment: your mentioned code has multiple lines. what is exactly this line here?? and there's nothing like the error in your mentioned code. debug your code to find out from where the error is coming.

Comment: I put  ' id="this_line" '   line that error mentioned.

Comment: Throw that error where use Shorthand If/Else condition ??